# Button group not allowing form to be posted

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor

I have a choice of radio buttons in a form however I am using them as button group. However I want to pass the value selected back to the controller. But its not posting back at all it just sits there any reason why a btn group would make a form behave in this way.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Relationships", FormMethod.Post, null)) { 

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <div class="btn-group type-select pull-left top-buffer add-on btn-group-lg" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="RealtionShipType" data-relationshiptype="1" style="display:none" value="1">
                <i class="fa fa-person-booth fa-4x"></i>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="RealtionShipType" data-relationshiptype="1" value="2">
                <i class="fa fa-ship fa-4x"></i>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="RealtionShipType" Value="3">
                <i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-4x"></i>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="RealtionShipType" data-relationshiptype="1" value="4">
                <i class="fa fa-brain fa-4x"></i>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="RealtionShipType" data-relationshiptype="1" value="5">
                <i class="fa fa-car fa-4x"></i>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="RealtionShipType" style="display:none" value="5">
                <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-4x"></i>
            </label>

        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Save And Edit">


    </div>
    }
```

I have included a .net fiddle for it as expierence the same situation there the form simply wont post.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FMiprT

Answer (score 2):

The outer button-group div:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
...
</div>
```

seems to be redundant, but it is also preventing your "submit" button's click event from firing (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#toggle-states for details). You don't need to put your submit button in toggle mode, only the radio buttons need this - and you already have another div around those to do that.

Just remove that div and the button works again.

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qeRX9I

Comment: I orignally had it to hide the radio button from the image as without it it appears if that makes since

Comment: No not really. What do you mean exactly? When I changed it in the dotnetfiddle it made no difference to the appearance. Not sure what image you're talking about.

Comment: I wasnt able to configure the font awsome in dotnet fiddle so didnt no how to show u

Comment: ok. But still I don't really know what you mean. Is it causing you a problem to remove this div? What exactly goes wrong? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with ADyson, it seems that the issue is related to the outer button-group div. After removing it, we could submit the form.

If you don't want to remove the outer button-group div, as a workaround,you could consider use the JQuery method to submit the form.

code like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="mainform" }))
{

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <div class="btn-group type-select pull-left top-buffer add-on btn-group-lg" data-toggle="buttons">
            ...
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Save And Edit"> 
    </div>
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-success").click(function () {
            //find the form and submit
            $(".mainform").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```